# Bootmetro tiles border colour

Tags: javascript, css, html, microsoft-metro

So I have been using the Bootmetro template but I have ran into a problem. You can view a demo [here](http://aozora.github.com/bootmetro/hub.html) and or download the source [here](http://aozora.github.com/bootmetro/).

The problem is when you hover over any of the tiles you will notice a border appear, its like a bluish colour.

[image]

Well I have spent the last hour trying to find the javascript or css file that has the settings for this but I cant seem to find it.

I was hoping someone might have some experience of Bootmetro/css/javascript and could point me in the right direction. All I am looking to do is change the border highlight colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bootmetro-tiles.css line 101:

```
.metro .tile:hover {
    outline: 3px solid #225A68;
}
```

(Firebug is your friend.)

Answer (score 0):

```
.metro .tile:hover {
      outline: 3px #225a68 solid;
   }
```

Line no 101 
File Bootmetro-tiles.css

Right click and inspect element